# Problem with converting to Array, TypeScript, React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I get a response from the server like this

```
const {data, error, isLoading: preloading, refetch}  = doctorAPI.useFetchDoctorsQuery()
console.log(data)
```

[image]
[image]

API function:

```
fetchDoctors: build.query<IDoctorShort[], PaginationDoctors>({

    query: (PaginationDoctorsForCertainDoctor) => ({
        url: '/doctors',
        params: {
            _doctorID: PaginationDoctorsForCertainDoctor.doctorID,
            _limit: PaginationDoctorsForCertainDoctor.limit,
            _numofpage: PaginationDoctorsForCertainDoctor.numofpage,
            _queryParams: PaginationDoctorsForCertainDoctor.queryParams,
        }
    }),
    providesTags: result => ['Doctor']
}),
```

I need to convert it to an Array in order to iterate over it.

I need an Array because it rises me an error that "array.map is not a function" in stableSort

```
function stableSort<T>(array: Array<T>, comparator: (a: T, b: T) => number) {
  console.log("StableSort")
  console.log(array)
  console.log(Array.isArray(array)) // return false 

  const stabilizedThis = array.map((el, index) => [el, index] as [T, number]);
  stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
    const order = comparator(a[0], b[0]);
    if (order !== 0) {
      return order;
    }
    return a[1] - b[1];
  });
  return stabilizedThis.map(el => el[0]);
}
```

The problem is that I can't iterate over a non-Array

I tried:

```
Array.from([...data]) // Returns an empty array
```

```
Array.from(data) // Returns an empty array
```

```
Array<IDoctorShort>data // IDoctorShort - interface // Nothing change
```

Comment: Try using `data.data` instead of just `data`. Looks like `data` is an object with a `data` property that is an array.

Comment: I get this error: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IDoctorShort[]'.

Comment: Seems like you've got the types wrong somewhere. Need to change `IDoctorShort[]` somewhere to `{data: IDoctorShort[]}`